# Make Request for a specific object in an API request

Tags: java, android

I have an API for a user profile that holds all the details about the user. Now i want to for instance get all countries and make a user select one country and save the user selection in context and do the same for city and region including the user details and when i am finally done i would send all as POST request to the server. How can i achieve this?

In this case below, i want to add a list of countries to a spinner and when the user clicks the spinner a drop down of countries served from the API is provided to the user.

This is my model for country below:

```
public class Country {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("pager")
@Expose
private Pager pager;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Pager getPager() {
    return pager;
}

public void setPager(Pager pager) {
    this.pager = pager;
}

}
```

Below is codes to get the names of the countries but unfortunately i am unable to get the names.

```
public void loadCountry() {
    mAPIService.loadCountry().enqueue(new Callback<Country>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<Country> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            String name = response.body().getName();
            Log.i("countryName", name);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddLocation.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, response.body().getName().indexOf(1));
            countrySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all I suggest you to ask a more specifiec question. 
You can use Volley to send GET and POST request to the server.
You should make a spinner view and add countries to it , do the same for the cities so the user can choose a country and a city using that then get the data from server using Volley GET request and parse that Json .
Make any change you want to the Json and post it to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your comment i am updating the question to be more specific. Kindly help here.